# Sudden absence without informing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the best word or idiom for someone who suddenly leaves/disappears without informing?

Answer (score 3):

AWOL - Absent WithOut Leave

> **AWOL** *adjective*
>   (Military)
>   *usually predicative*
>   Absent from where one should be but without intent to desert.
>   ‘the men have gone AWOL’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/awol)

Pronunciation, [courtesy of @Andrew Leach](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377748/sudden-absence-without-informing/377749?noredirect=1#comment886504_377749): "Aywol" /ˈeɪwɒl/.

Comment: And it's pronounced as a word, "Aywol" /ˈeɪwɒl/

Comment: For those of you wondering about the letter 'o' making a four-letter acronym for a three-word phrase, authorized absence from the military is AWL, absent *with* leave.

Comment: I never knew about the "without intent to desert" bit. I always thought "AWOL" meant they were suspected of deserting.